# Can i use route ID for Link template 'edit-form' for entity type?

Tags: 8, entities

Can i use route ID for Link template 'edit-form' for entity type?

I'm following [this tutorial](https://wunder.io/blog/configuration-entities-in-drupal-8/2014-07-14)

over there he use:

```
 *   links = {
 *     "edit-form" = "flower.edit",
 *     "delete-form" = "flower.delete"
 *   }
```

while flower.edit (i assume) is from below route.yml:

```
flower.edit:
  path: '/admin/structure/flowers/edit/{flower}'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'flower.edit'
    _title: 'Edit flower'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer site configuration'
```

but when i run, it throw me an error:

> Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\Exception\InvalidLinkTemplateException: "Link
>   template 'edit-form' for entity type 'flower' must start with a
>   leading slash, the current link template is
>   'flower.edit'" at
>   \core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager.php
>   line 97

I know i can just use: `/admin/structure/flowers/edit/{flower}` to solve my problem.

but the question is: is it actually possible to use route (instead of path) in entity links config?

Comment: The tutorial is from 2014, since then the form links have changed from routes to paths.

Comment: so, the answer is: not possible, it can only accept paths?

Comment: See change record https://www.drupal.org/node/2382937

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial is from 2014. Since then the link templates have changed from route to path. See [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2382937):

**Previous link template format**

```
   links = {
     "canonical" = "entity.node.canonical",
     "edit-form" = "entity.node.edit_form",
     "delete-form" = "entity.node.delete_form",
   }
```

**New link template format**

After the change, the path is used.

```
   links = {
     "canonical" = "/node/{node}",
     "edit-form" = "/node/{node}/edit",
     "delete-form" = "/node/{node}/delete",
   }
```